# How to add an onChange event to Django form fields with field itself as an argument

Tags: javascript, python-2.7, django-forms

I'm adding `onChange` event on a TextField dynamically. The following code explains what I'm doing:

```
fields.widget.attrs['onchange'] = 'execute_function(arg)'
```

I have add field itself as an argument to javascript function similar to `function_name(this)` in django forms.

I want to pass the field itself to execute_function() as an argument to the function.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question it should be as easy as changing `arg` to `this`:

```
fields.widget.attrs['onchange'] = 'execute_function(this)'
```