# Django dropdown only using the django widget form passing selected item

Tags: python, django, select, widget

Hi so I want to create a dropdown menu with only the django forms. So I know by default it is using the select widget.

```
class PrivacyForm(forms.Form):
    visibility =forms.ChoiceField(required=True,choices=Posts.Post_Privacy_CHOICES, initial=1)

    Post_Privacy_CHOICES = (
      (1, 'Public'),
      ('oFo', 'only Followers'),
      ('oM', 'only Me'),
 )
```

Ok so i get a normal dropdown with those choices. But when  I change the dropdown to only Me or only Followers I want to call a function with the given selected argument and preferable a function in views.py and I also want the choice to be saved not the default.
So I know there is something like

```
widget=forms.Select(attrs={"onChange":'refresh()')
```

, but I dont find anything to that in the Django docs and it does not seem to work.
I hope you can help me.

Comment: Try like this: `forms.Select(attrs={"onChange":'refresh()'})`

Comment: hm I get a syntax error SyntaxError at /profile/scotty/
invalid syntax (forms.py, line 8).                                                                                 visibility = forms.ChoiceField(required=True,choices=Posts.Post_Privacy_CHOICES, initial=1, widget=forms.Select(attrs={"onChange":'refresh()'))

Comment: by the way where do I define the function refresh? i defined it in the form model

Comment: Check this [questions and its comment](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24281544/3945375). That is a JS function, you should define it as a JS function, or you could use the `submit` method.

Comment: Yea I thought maybe there is a different solution without using javascript or without submit, because the submit method generates a button. But thanks anyway